# Fast flipping between front and back cameras in Camera1 API?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am aware that Camera2 API allows access to both cameras however I am focused on reusing old retired phones as part of a sensor network project. My understanding is that for the older Camera1 API only one camera could be opened for use at a time and then would need to be released before making use of second (except on a limited range of models whose manufacturers had elected to provide additional capabilities) which [according to this post can take over one second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114727/different-switch-times-between-front-and-back-cameras-in-android) - is there any way around this in order to be able able to flip between the two cameras on legacy devices? I'm looking to capture at least 4FPS on each camera in order to do visual odometry.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no.  Most devices only have one hardware processing pipeline, and it's shared between the two camera sensors.  So one camera has to be shut down before the other can be started.

Camera2 doesn't guarantee simultaneous access, either, unfortunately. Both APIs can run multiple cameras at once if the device hardware allows.  For the old API, there's no way to query if concurrent use is possible, so the only way to find out is to try it.  But most likely, it won't.